# Geolocation get country name

Tags: python, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

I was wondering if there is a simple way to retrive the country name of the given city.

Meaning that I will provide the city name and it will give me back the country.

For now the only thing I can think of is reversegeo,
but it only gives me the short for the country and I need the full name.

```
def reverseGeocode(coordinates):
    result = rg.search(coordinates,mode=1)
    print(result)
    
cord= (36.8968908,30.7133233)
reverseGeocode(cord)
```

Results:

```
[{'lat': '36.90812', 'lon': '30.69556', 'name': 'Antalya', 'admin1': 'Antalya', 'admin2': '', 'cc': 'TR'}]
```

Is there anyway to do it? or maybe to get the full name somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I kept searching for the best way to do that and I found something that I will like to share with others we wants the same as me.

https://pypi.org/project/geocoder/

All I add to do is to install the library

```
pip install geocoder
import geocoder as rg
def reverseGeocode(coordinates):
    result = rg.osm(coordinates, method='reverse')
    print(result.json['country'])
```

I built a function and now you can call it with the lat,lng values.

```
cord= (36.8968908,30.7133233)
reverseGeocode(cord)
```

The only problem is that you will get the country name by the country language.

EDIT: Found the best solution.

```
import googlemaps as gm
def reverseGeocode(cords):
    gmaps = gm.Client(key=api)
    res = gmaps.reverse_geocode(cords)
    country = res[-1]['address_components'][0]['long_name']
    return country

cord = (lat,lng)
reverseGeocode(cord)
```

Works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [`reverse_geocode`](https://pypi.org/project/reverse-geocode/):

```
import reverse_geocode

coordinates = (36.8968908,30.7133233),
print(reverse_geocode.search(coordinates))
```

`coordinates` must be iterable, hence the `,` after the coordinates, to make the variable into a tuple.

Output:

```
[{'country_code': 'TR', 'city': 'Kepez', 'country': 'Turkey'}]
```

`reverse_geocode` needs to download a file once, so it's not completely offline, but once the file is downloaded the code should work even without an internet connection.

Comment: that doesnt work for me,
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 464: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? It works locally and on Google Colab, both of which use Python 3.

Comment: Sorry it's probably working, I just didnt download the file you talked about.

Comment: The file should be downloaded automatically if you run the code, when you call `.search` there is a check to see if the file exists locally and if not it's downloaded. Once it is downloaded it shouldn't download that file anymore and you can run the code offline, but the first time you need to be online to get the file.

Comment: So it didn't work for me, running python 3.10 working on Jupyter

Comment: You might want to ask a new question about this particular problem (with [mcve] and stack trace), I can't immediately see what could cause that issue for you.

Comment: Thanks ok, I apprecitate your help but I have managed to solve it